# Match all documents in a search index

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I have a search index of documents and I would like to send a query to get all of them. Is that possible?

Note:
It seems that "/" or "?" work but only on my dev server. When deployed to prod these queries do not return any result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '?' or '/' that works for you on the dev_server shouldn't have happened. The docs on [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/#Python_Index_schemas) link says that the punctuators including the '?' or '/' act as word tokenizers only.

In order to retrieve all the results i would suggest a smart way to index the documents, maybe use another field using which such a solution is possible. A type `date` field, and a `created_at` query on a - created_at > *epoch_time* or something similar from the past.